# проблема с ActionBar-ом

Tags: android, actionbar, genymotion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при запуске проекта, на Genymotion эмуляторе(Android 4.2) не отображается ActionBar, а на эмуляторе(Android 5.0) отображается

Comment: Покажите файл с меню

Comment: А код то есть ?

Comment: @OldBlood Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: @OldBlood, так мы с вами каши не сварим. Не надо ссылок на левые ресурсы - дополняйте вопрос через правку. Пока что вам помочь никак - вы информацию необходимую скрываете